# If $x=y^2+z^2$, $y=z^2+x^2$, and $z=x^2+y^2$, prove $\frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{y}{y+1} + \frac{z}{z+1} = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x=y^2+z^2$, $y=z^2+x^2$, and $z=x^2+y^2$,
prove
$$\frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{y}{y+1} + \frac{z}{z+1}  = 1$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: It's actually not as tough as it seems. x+x²=y+y²+z+z² and think about the sign of x,y,z. What can you conclude from this?

Comment: @ user600016 I don't agree with your relationship.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is an evident solution $x=y=z=0$ for which the second identity is... false.

We will assume $x,y,z \neq 0$ in the following.

A first remark is that, evidently $x,y,z >0$

Let us call (1),(2),(3) your equations.

Make the difference (1)-(2):

$$x-y=y^2-x^2 \ \iff x-y=-(x-y)(x+y)$$

Let us assume for a while that  $x-y=0$ : in this case, we would deduce that  $x+y=-1$ which is impossible due to the positivity of y o$x $ and $y$.

Therefore, $x=y$.

For the same reason, using difference (1)-(3), we get $x=z$.

Replacing $y$ and $z$ by $x$ in any of the 3 equations, we get $x=2x^2$. As $x \ne 0$, we deduce that $x=\tfrac12$ and globally :

$$x=y=z=\tfrac12$$

We can check that with these values, the targetted relationship is indeed fullfilled.

Comment: If two of them were equal, wouldn't that make the division of, say $z-y$ be division by 0

Comment: @Plato After assuming the equality of 2 of them, I haven't any more to divide by such a quantity.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense. Good answer.

Comment: I have simplified my argumentation.

Comment: Yes, that's more direct. Thanks

Comment: Strange downvoting... But I am accustomed.

Comment: Is my answer convenient for you ?

Comment: Ya sure. But I'm not the OP

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

From the first two,

$$x-y=y^2-x^2$$ factors as $$(x-y)(x+y+1)=0$$

which defines a pair of planes, and similarly
$$(z-x)(z+x+1)=0.$$

Eliminate $y,z$ and plug in the last identity.

---

Note that

$$\frac{-(x+1)}{-(x+1)+1}=\frac{x+1}{x}$$

and the last identity has one of the forms

$$3t=1,\\2t+t^{-1}=1,\\t+2t^{-1}=1.$$